# Convert WPF application to Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have WPF Application. Is it possible to quickly convert WPF app to Silvelight application, if not which technic I have to use to transform my WPF app to Silverlight. And also I want to know about limitations of Silvelight app.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible to quickly convert a WPF application to Silverlight, for example:-

```
 <TextBlock Text="Hello, World" />
```

will convert with hardly any changes.  Does that help?  Clearly not.  It really does depend on how much stuff from WPF your app uses that isn't in Silverlight.

You should read through the [WPF Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(v=VS.95).aspx) section of the Silverlight documentation to assess how much of your WPF application will port to Silverlight.

What are the limitations of a Silverlight app?  Well it can't make a decent cup of tea I know that.  Seriously thats far too broad a question.  Define what sort of things the app does and that'll guide the advice you get.

For example, is it a LOB app?  Does need access to the local file system?  Does it depend on third-party components?  etc.

Comment: Yes this is Document Managment system which widely use COM interop with Word , Excel. And also there is a big functionality with file system IO.

Comment: Silverlight 4 out-of-browser apps support COM interop, so it might not be a problem to communicate with Office.
But be aware that the Silverlight runtime is only a subset of the .Net runtime on which WPF runs, and a lot of APIs are not available to Silverlight, even in out-of-browser mode.
Before attempting a migration do a careful study of incompatibilities.

Comment: @Polaris: as @Serious points out COM interop is availalbe (only with OOB __with__ elevated trust).  My question though would be if you need to use that when you have a WPF app already why port at all?  The only the good reason I can think off would be to reach out to Mac users but automation whilst coming isn't really there yet.

Comment: I have requirement from customer to give web access to the app functionality for remote users, like simple web page. This is main reason why I think about Silverlight. @AnthonyWJones thank you very much for link. I have read about very important Silverlight limitations which can create problems for me in future.